# Javascript override user mouse event

Tags: javascript, mouse

I have a bit of javascript that will allow the user to move stuff around using the mouse, so the user can click and drag things around, which is working all fine, but what I am struggling with is being able to override the users click event.

So what I am trying to do is, if the user moves the item to a certain position I want to stop the click and hold event, this would mean the user would have to the go an reselect the item again and click and drag again.

Can you override the users mouse action from javascript? It seems simple but I am unable to find a way in my javascript to stop the mousehold event

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override `onmousedown` to store the mouse coordinates and fire the "real click" event on `onmouseup` if the mouse position did not changed (or if the change is less than say 5 pixels).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myElement').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // here is your override
    doSomethingElse();  // or not
});
```

Same thing for IE but use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of blocking events, you can put some logic inside your `onclick` handler to check for this condition?

For example, maybe a couple of properties to maintain state. You could call one `itemSelected`, which must be `true` in order for the the item to move. Then if you set `itemSelected` to `false`, another click will be necessary to toggle it again.